# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, internal

I'm using Windows 7 and getting the following error. This was not when I was using Windows XP.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this application marked as an application?

Also, have you tried running the application in Native mode?

Answer (score 0):

It is *likely* that this error is due to your **application pool running in Integrated mode** in IIS 7.

Can you check if it is running in Integrated mode.

If so, try converting the application pool to run in **classic mode** and see if that helps get rid of this error.

For a better understanding of what Integrated mode in iIS 7 is and why it might be causing issues, you can also read [this article here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/243/aspnet-integration-with-iis-7/)